# Return a List from Controller to View after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ImportListByVesselVoyage()
{    
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportListByVesselVoyage(WebTrackParam param)
{
        client = new HttpClient();
        List<ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV> appMenu = new List<ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("/Services/WebTrack.svc/ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBVJSONData/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}/{6}/{7}/{8}/{9}/{10}", "VR", "2018", param.reg, " ", " ", "A", "A", "S,Y,D", "F,L,E,T", "ITTEST", "2")).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JObject result = JObject.Parse(stringData);
                var appMenuarray = result["ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBVResult"].Value<JArray>();
                appMenu = appMenuarray.ToObject<List<ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>>();
                ViewBag.ILBV = appMenu;
            }

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return PartialView("ImportListByVesselVoyage", appMenu);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
            client = null;
        }
}
```

**View**

```
 @model List<WebTrack.Models.ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportListByVesselVoyage", "Containerized", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     <div class="box-body">
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reg)
            </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
       </div>
      <div id="result">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body no-padding">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Container No.</th>
                        <th>Operator</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Size</th>
                        <th>Commodity</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Discharged</th>
                        <th>Delivered</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ILBV)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.ContainerNo</td>
                            <td>@item.Operator</td>
                            <td>@item.Status</td>
                            <td>@item.Size</td>
                            <td>@item.Commodity</td>
                            <td>@item.Destination</td>
                            <td>@item.Location</td>
                            <td>@item.Discharged</td>
                            <td>@item.Delivered</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer clearfix">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  }
```

I will get the "reg" from the @Html.TextBox() and will pass it to the *[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportListByVesselVoyage(WebTrackParam param)*.
I would like to know how to return the result appMenu to my view. And I've tried to use ViewBag.ILBV but since it's on the HttpPost, it will cause null error during the Get.

Thank you, I hope you understand my concern. I'm new to MVC.

Comment: did you mention the @model properly at the top of your view?

Comment: Yes, I have. My main problem is that I get the null error when I use ViewBag from the HttpPost because it has no value from the get method.

Comment: Viewbag is not used for round trips. You can only send data through controller to view in viewbag. If you want the data to be present in the next request, use sessions

Comment: Do not use `ViewBag`. Create a `List<ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>` in the method and return that to the view and use `@foreach (var item in Model)` (in the GET method just use `return View(new List<ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>());` to return an empty collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I've tried to use ViewBag.ILBV but since it's on the HttpPost, it will cause null error during the Get.

So write your `View` as follows:

```
@model List<WebTrack.Models.ImportListByVesselVoyageGetILBV>   
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportListByVesselVoyage", "Containerized", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     <div class="box-body">
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reg)
            </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
       </div>
      <div id="result">

    @{
       if(ViewBag.ILBV != null)
       {
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="box">
                   <div class="box-body no-padding">
                       <table class="table table-striped">
                         <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <th>Container No.</th>
                              <th>Operator</th>
                              <th>Status</th>
                              <th>Size</th>
                              <th>Commodity</th>
                              <th>Destination</th>
                              <th>Location</th>
                              <th>Discharged</th>
                              <th>Delivered</th>
                           </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ILBV)
                        {
                          <tr>
                              <td>@item.ContainerNo</td>
                              <td>@item.Operator</td>
                              <td>@item.Status</td>
                              <td>@item.Size</td>
                              <td>@item.Commodity</td>
                              <td>@item.Destination</td>
                              <td>@item.Location</td>
                              <td>@item.Discharged</td>
                              <td>@item.Delivered</td>
                          </tr>
                       }
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
               </div>
               <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right"></ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Nivram Glad to hear that! Thank you too.